# Android Studio - Problema al enviar información mediante un Intent

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos

Estoy intentando enviar información mediante un intent, que la enviaría al hacer click en distintos elementos de una lista.

Lo que necesito hacer es que, al tocar determinado elemento de la lista, me envíe la información de los campos "titulo" y "autor" de una tabla que tengo en una BD (esta tabla tiene 10 registros con distintos campos) según el id que yo le diga.

Por ejemplo: para el elemento 1 de la lista, al hacerle click, me tiene que llevar a otra activity junto con el "titulo" y "autor" del registro id=1.

El código para hacer esto es el siguiente:

```
    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    BaseDeDatos admin = new BaseDeDatos(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = admin.getWritableDatabase();
    Libros catego = null;
    listaLibros = new ArrayList<>();
    cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from libros" , null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        catego = new Libros();
        catego.setId(cursor.getString(0));
        catego.setTitulo(cursor.getString(1));
        catego.setAutor(cursor.getString(2));
        listaLibros.add(catego);
        }

        String info = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if (position == 0 ) {
                for (Libros libro : listaLibros) {
                    if (libro.getId().equals("1")) {
                        Intent terror = new Intent(Terror.this, DatosLibro.class);
                        terror.putExtra("titulo", libro.getTitulo());
                        terror.putExtra("autor", libro.getAutor());
                        startActivity(terror);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Acá le estoy diciendo que si toco el primer elemento del ListView `(position==0)`, me mande a otra activity con el "titulo" y "autor" del primer registro de la tabla (`id=1`)

Esto funciona perfectamente sin ningún problema, **el problema** es que sólo funciona para el primer registro de la tabla (`id=1`). Si quiero hacer lo mismo pero con el "titulo" y "autor" de por ejemplo, el tercer registro de la tabla (`id=3`), entonces solo debería modificar el "1" por el "3" en esta linea:

```
if (libro.getId().equals("3")) {
```

Pero cuando lo hago, al tocar el elemento de la lista, no pasa nada. Tampoco me da ningún error ni nada por el estilo, simplemente **no hace nada**.

En resumen lo que necesito hacer es, mediante el Intent, que me lleve a la activity DatosLibros pero con el "titulo" y "autor" de otro registro que no sea el primero en mi tabla (`id=1`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La  variable `position` indica el indice del elemento que haces clic, si defines

```
   if (position == 0 ) {
     ...
     ... 
   }
```

únicamente realizará lo que se encuentra dentro del bloque cuando das click al primer elemento.

---

Si no obtiene los datos del elemento indicado, en este caso cuando `libro.getId().equals("4")`:

```
        if (position == 0 ) {
            for (Libros libro : listaLibros) {
                if (libro.getId().equals("4")) {
                    Intent terror = new Intent(Terror.this, DatosLibro.class);
                    terror.putExtra("titulo", libro.getTitulo());
                    terror.putExtra("autor", libro.getAutor());
                    startActivity(terror);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

El problema puedes ser **da la impresión que hay algo raro con los registros. Te sugiero primero eliminar la aplicación y volver a subirla me parece que esto puede solucionar el problema.**

Comment: claro @Jorgesys , eso está bien que sea así. Cuando doy click al primer elemento, quiero que me mande a la otra activity con el "autor" y "titulo" del tercer registro de mi tabla, pero no funciona.

Comment: El código debería de funcionar me da la impresión que hay algo raro con los registros. Te sugiero primero eliminar la aplicación y volver a subirla me parece que esto puede solucionar el problema. Si esto no funciona imprime en el for : for (Libros libro : listaLibros) { los valores de libro.getTitulo() y libro.getAutor() para asegurar son registros con valores diferentes.

Comment: tenías razon! desinstale e installe la app y me dió algunos errores en la generación de los registros, hice unas modificaciones y ahora todo funciona perfecto y como debería :D muchas gracias por toda tu ayuda @Jorgesys

Comment: @Rodrigo era muy raro que no funcionara, en realidad se había creado una BD con una versión de la tabla con datos incorrectos, un placer ayudarte saludos!

Comment: sip, era eso, pero era muy raro lo que pasaba ya que información me traía y no daba errores. Muchas gracias de nuevo!!